# average function not working properly, what is wrong with it?

Tags: javascript, html, function, average

I am a newbie in studying Javascript, why is my function not viewing the correct answer? Can you help me understand what is the problem with it.
Because if the computation is < 70 it should be C, etc...

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
     <script>
         function type() {
            let maths = prompt('Please type grade in Math');
            let physics = prompt('Please type grade in Physics');
            let chemistry = prompt('Please type grade Chemistry');
                
            let grade = (maths + physics + chemistry)/3;
                    
               if (grade < 70) {
                  document.write('Your grade is: ' + 'C')
               } else if (grade > 70 && grade < 90) {
                  document.write('Your grade is: ' + 'B')
               } else {
                  document.write('Your grade is: ' + 'A');
               }
        }
        type();


     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Haven't tried the code and you did not tell us what is wrong with it (by example) but at least change the second condition from grade > 70 to grade >= 70.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that [prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) returns a string, not a number. The below example converts it to a number using [parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) so that you can calculate the average.

It would be better to use [number inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp), which allow you to set minimum and maximum allowed values and handle some validation for you.

Also, not sure it makes sense that if I enter 0 for each class I still get a C.

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
     <script>
         function type() {
            let maths = parseFloat(prompt('Please type grade in Math'));
            let physics = parseFloat(prompt('Please type grade in Physics'));
            let chemistry = parseFloat(prompt('Please type grade Chemistry'));
                
            let grade = (maths + physics + chemistry)/3;
                    
               if (grade < 70) {
                  document.write('Your grade is: ' + 'C')
               } else if (grade > 70 && grade < 90) {
                  document.write('Your grade is: ' + 'B')
               } else {
                  document.write('Your grade is: ' + 'A');
               }
        }
        type();


     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @Mark you're welcome! Keep learning and good luck with it :)